# Multiple named animations

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

I am new to blender and I am trying to model, texture and animate a character like the avatar from Minecraft and I am stuck on the animation part.

What I would like to do is to create several animations (Stand, Walk, Kick etc) by using rotation keyframes for the various body parts.

What I can't figure out how to create some sort of group, like Walk, than have several actions inside it.

I thought I was going to be able to use the Timeline to keyframe the body part and then somehow associate and name that in the Dope sheet but I am stumped at this point.

(I am trying to do this without rigging the model)

Comment: As far as I know, you can not have multiple object-level animations in one action. You need to rig your model, then it is easy to use the dope sheet or action editor to switch between multiple actions.

Comment: Thanks @HENDRIX, I guess that means I have to learn rigging then. If you add that comment as an answer I'll accept it so that you get the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the parts to a single object and animate shape keys. Not 100% what you asked for, but this could be a good work arround.

[image: multiple shape key NLA]

Comment: There is limitation with rotations - shapekeys won't support it. But else for linear motion this can be a way.

Comment: Shape keys don't handle rotations well. You'll find that the rotating cube also changes size inbetween endpoints.

Comment: Although it is clumsily possible if you layer different shape keys over eachother. Only why would I with having bones around...

Answer (score 0):

for complex armature animation you need to learn NLA (non linear animation)
so you can block every simple animation made in Dope sheet like a walk run jump and so on, mixing them togheter in non linear fashion

you need to deep learn the use of dope sheet and NLE
if you are really interested in i suggest you to attend an animation course since animation is one of the most complex thing to learn in general not only in Blender 
you will save a lot of time

Comment: This answer is not really that helpful. Telling the OP that he should attend an animation course is not the answer to "how create multiple animations"

Comment: i think i correctly answered to the main question about mixing multiple actions